# metadata tag not found with describeType in production

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am using describeType and am able to get all of the variable and accessor metadata tags just fine in local debug, local test suite or local air build. Our web app running this code also sees the metadata just fine in production (running with browser plugin).  But, our production air desktop app throws my error "can't find metadata". When I added some logging code (being thoroughly confused LOL) I discovered that the metadata property in the XML from describeType is empty?!?

My only thought is that we use gradle and run a bunch of custom scripts during the actual build process... but HOW could that be either removing or making unreadable class metadata tags?

I've tried standard v/s custom tags, accessors v/s variables, describeType(instance) v/s describeType(class) and all of these give same result... all variations work everywhere every time except in production desktop build.

Anyone with ANY thoughts on this... please chime in.  I've been pulling my hair out with this one!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it turns out my "only thought" was the correct answer.  after digging deeper I found that the keep-as3-metadata that was on our compiler options was not up to date in our grade build scripts and didn't include the tags we were using for this.  Thank god!!! LOL.